# What exactly is the variance on the parameters of SciPy curve fit? (Python)

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm currently using the curve_fit function of the scipy.optimize package in Python, and know that if you take the square root of the diagonal entries of the covariance matrix that you get from curve_fit, you get the standard deviation on the parameters that curve_fit calculated. What I'm not sure about, is what exactly this standard deviation means. It's an approximation using a Hesse matrix as far as I understand, but what would the exact calculation be? Standard deviation on the Gaussian Bell Curve tells you what percentage of area is within a certain range of the curve, so I assumed for curve_fit it tells you how many datapoints are between certain parameter values, but apparently that isn't right...

I'm sorry if this should be basic knowledge for curve fitting, but I really can't figure out what the standard deviations do, they express an error on the parameters, but those parameters are calculated as the best possible fit for the function, it's not like there's a whole collection of optimal parameters, and we get the average value of that collection and consequently also have a standard deviation. There's only one optimal value, what is there to compare it with? I guess my question really comes down to this: how can I manually and accurately calculate these standard deviations, and not just get an approximation using a Hesse matrix?

Comment: how is this question related to `python` or `scipy` though? This is more appropriate for wikipedia

Comment: I wasn't sure where to post the question, I thought python and scipy were appropriate subjects as that's where the question arose for me personally... Should I have posted it elsewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The variance in the fitted parameters represents the uncertainty in the best-fit value based on the quality of the fit of the model to the data.   That is, it describes by how much the value could change away from the best-fit value and still have a fit that is almost as good as the best-fit value.

With standard definition of chi-square,
   `chi_square = ( ( (data - model)/epsilon )**2 ).sum()`

and `reduced_chi_square = chi_square / (ndata - nvarys)` (where `data` is the array of the data values, `model` the array of the calculated model, `epsilon` is uncertainty in the data, `ndata` is the number of data points, and `nvarys` the number of variables), a good fit should have `reduced_chi_square` around 1 or `chi_square` around `ndata-nvary`. (Note: not 0 -- the fit will not be perfect as there is noise in the data).

The variance in the best-fit value for a variable gives the amount by which you can change the value (and re-optimize all other values) and increase chi-square by 1. That gives the so-called '1-sigma' value of the uncertainty.

As you say, these values are expressed in the diagonal terms of the covariance matrix returned by `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` (the off-diagonal terms give the correlations between variables: if a value for one variable is changed away from its optimal value, how would the others respond to make the fit better).  This covariance matrix is built using the trial values and derivatives near the solution as the fit is being done -- it calculates the "curvature" of the parameter space (ie, how much chi-square changes when a variables value changes).

You *can* calculate these uncertainties by hand. The `lmfit` library (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) has routines to more explicitly explore the confidence intervals of variables from least-squares minimization or curve-fitting.  These are described in more detail at
https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/confidence.html.  It's probably easiest to use `lmfit` for the curve-fitting rather than trying to re-implement the confidence interval code for `curve_fit`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it makes a lot more sense! I'll try out the lmfit and see how the confidence intervals look like!